# Getting error #13 in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, highcharts

I am using Highcharts using backbone framework. I have `div` in `template.html`, and loading chart in `someview.ts` file. My code looks like following, `View.ts`: loading the below function through ajax call inside initialize function

```
renderChart()
{ 
    var mychartoptions: Highchartoptions{ chart: {type:'bar', renderTo:'ColumnChart'} } 
}
```

template.html:

But I am getting the TypeError#13, after some time when refreshes page. Please give me correct approach, what would be wrong in my code.

Comment: Does your `div` have `id='ColumnChart'`?

Comment: Just check whether an element with id `ColumnChart` available before you render it. If renderChart is being called by some async callback, problem could be that, when you are trying to render chart, parent element is not available in the DOM